# QTreeView 'show-decoration-selected: 0;' has no effect

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am running `PyQt4` and trying to make a `QTreeWidget` with no decoration color on selected items. However the following code has no effect and the color of the left-side of the `QTreeWidgetItem` is still being colored upon selection.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.tree)
        for i in range(20):
            item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
            item.setText(0, 'This Is Item #{}'.format(i))
            for i in range(4):
                child_item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item)

        self.tree.setStyleSheet('''
            QTreeView{
                show-decoration-selected: 0;
            }
        ''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When you say the left side of the QTreeWidgetItem are you talking about the expand arrow or something else? "show-decoration-selected" should change whether that arrow glows if the item (the text in column one) is hovered over

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selection color and background color on `QTreeView::item` and set the background for `QTreeView::branch`. However, when you override the branch background you will need to include the image used for the branch arrows. Here are the ones provided by Qt.

branch-closed -  [image: branch closed]

branch-open - [image]

```
QTreeView::item {
    selection-color: #000;
    selection-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0%);
}
QTreeView::branch:selected:closed {
    background: white;
    image: url(branch-closed.png);
}
QTreeView::branch:selected:open {
    background: white;
    image: url(branch-open.png);
}
```